# Interesting instantaneous rate of change problem?

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

I'm currently enrolled in a calculus I course, we currently have an exam coming up in the next few weeks so I wanted to get some practice in before then. However, when I came across this problem I was stumped -- I'm not even sure how begin a problem like this. I understand that the "instantaneous rate of change" is basically synonymous for "find the derivative" but how do I go about finding the derivative if I don't have the points for R or S?

[Link to the math problem and graph here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGlNX.png)

EDIT: Here is a live graph to show what I'm talking about [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6roooyp9gg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Q$ is on the graph, so you can write down an expression for the coordinates of $Q$. From that, you can find the equation of the line through $P$ and $Q$, and the location of the midpoint $S$ of the segment $PQ$, then the equation of the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$, then the coordinates of the point $R$, then the length of the segment $RS$. And having an equation for the length of $RS$ as a function of $x$, you know how to find the instantaneous rate of change.

Comment: That would work in theory, and I appreciate you taking the time to look at the problem, but it turns out that Q actually isn't a 'set point'. It turns out that Q is a moving point, like every other point on the graph. I know that the slop of PQ will tell me the slope of RS, but I'm still not sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Start at the beginning. Write down an expression for the coordinates of $Q$. I know $Q$ is moving – those coordinates that you will write down will have a variable in them.